# How to implement an activity into another?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, tabview

I don't know if it's a dumb question because it is one of my first apps.. but if that's the case, please also explain why!

If I create a Tab-Based Activity-Structure, I get nearly what I am asking for but only for Tabs. What I want is generally opening a second or even third activity in one main-activity which contains the main-interface.

Example: I have a Title-Bar and a little icon at the bottom-left corner for some reason during the whole app runtime. Now: How can I control them with the main activity and open at the same time some other activities/views into the existing interface? It should then be shown below the title bar and lying underneath the little icon (the icon is not really important, just fictional). Also it would be nice if I could add some fade in effects to these embedded activities/views. Is that somehow possible?

I currently only know, how to open activities each over another filling the whole screen, except in the case of tabs... maybe I only haven't inspected the tab structure enough.. however, I would be delighted about each answer!

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for, are [Fragments.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Fragments can be used to fill a part of the screen, while doing something else entirely in a different one.
In your example you can create a main activity that contains two `Fragments`.  One `Fragment` controls the title bar, the other one controls the main content area.
By replacing the current `Fragment` in your content area with a different one on the press of a button, you can achieve the behavior you are looking for. At least, that's how I did it in an app of mine containing a main content area and a music player. The music player stays in place while the main content changes.

Sadly I can't provide any example code right now, but here is a tutorialthat should help you get started:

- [Android User Interface Design: Working With Fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

Comment: Android 3.0, huh? I am using 2.3.6 ... otherwise this were the 100% correct answer - thanks.

Comment: It works on lower versions as well ;) 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html
The compatibility package makes it possible for Android versions down to 1.6 to use `Fragments` among other things.  My own app is based on 2.3.3 so I can promise you it works. Here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/  I pasted the wrong tutorial last time